# epoll and hash table in threads

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, epoll

I have mutli threaded application with worker threads, I'm using a hash table to route messages between two opend sd(socket descriptores), each thread is waiting with epoll_wait for a new connection so when new sd is created it will be added to the hash and it will start routing messges. is it ok to remove from the hash with no mutex lock? or is the assumption below correct?

The reason I'm thinking about it is becuase I will remove from the hash and it should be safe as the new sd # won't have the same sd # saved in hash unless it's closed with close(sd).

```
//Global var
struct route_table {
       int from_sd;
       int to_sd;
};

//end of global var
int main()
{
     route_table = malloc(sizeof(struct route_table) * file-max); //allocate an array for all fds from /proc/sys/fs/file-max

}


void *worker_function(void *)//lpthread
{
   epoll_wait()
  if (events & EPOLLIN)
  {
   if (route_table[fd].from_sd == fd)
           send_msg(route_table[fd].to_sd, msg)
  }

  if (events & EPOLLERR)
//EPOLLERR above is just an example, I'm covering all other errors
  {
   if (route_table[fd].from_sd == fd) {
           route_table[fd].to_sd   = 0; //remove from hash
           route_table[fd].from_sd = 0; //remove from hash then another worker thread starts working, so the other worker won't hit the same slot as the sd is still open for this thread
           shutdown(sd, SHUT_RDWR);//we don't care about this one
           close(sd); //now control is back for this thread then this sd will be removed and now new thread can have the same sd # with no problem
   }
  }    


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code sample isn't all that clear.  How do the threads relate to each other?  Places like epoll_wait() aren't showing the normal arguments.  Most typically a single thread will call epoll_wait() to service multiple fd's.  However if you have multiple threads doing their own epoll_wait() and then referring back to a hash table, most likely that hash needs MT-protection.